# Remove Duplicates based on 2 columns in ObjectList

Tags: vba

I want to remove duplicated values in my Table. It is ListObject Table with 1000s of lines.
I cannot get to work my code and I am using function RemoveDuplicates for ranges with the condition to delete the lines in the table if there are duplicates in 2 relative columns.

This is how it looks before running the code:

[image]

In my code, based on column C:C and E:E only, I need to check if each line has any duplicates within these 2 columns and delete them, leaving only one.

And this is my desired outcome:

[image]

This is my code that does not work. I am not sure if it is because my table is the List Object or because I assign Array wrong?

```
Sub test_Duplicate()
  Dim endrow As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4")

      With ws
        endrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(endrow, 6))
        rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlNo
    End With


End Sub
```

I will appreciate any help.
I noticed that whether my data is in the table as List Object or whether is it without it, I am getting the error nr 9 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Just change the **TableName** ..Mine is `Table1`

```
Sub test_Duplicate()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4")

    With ws
        .Range("Table1[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header:=xlYes
    End With


End Sub
```

Table Name is found on the `Design` Tab when you select the table.

Comment: Still nothing. I am getting error 9. But even if I am trying to do that without list Object, I am getting the same error. It does not work for multiple columns.

Comment: @Dozens .. It works.. I tried it on My worksheet. What is the Name of your table ?

Comment: The same. The name of the table is not the problem. Even if it was different I could change it, like that is a basic so it is not the problem

Comment: The debug stops on the line with RemoveDuplicates

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I  managed to find by looking through web.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet4")

With ws
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
    If .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(A" & i & ":A" & iLastRow & "=A" & i & ")," & _
    "--(I" & i & ":I" & iLastRow & "=I" & i & "))") > 1 Then
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 9)
    Else
    Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 9))
    End If
    End If
    Next i

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete

End With

 End Sub
```